# Removing all edges to a node except the shortest one

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph where a couple of nodes are connected to all other nodes by edges. This was done with this code;(so there already was a graph Z1 with nodes that were connected by a couple edges.)

```
for i in range (38,41 ):
    Z1.add_node(i)
for i in range (38,41):
    for j in range (0,38)):       
       Z1.add_edge(i, j)
```

After this i gave all the edges a weight equal to the distance between the nodes.

```
    for i,j in Z1.edges():
        Z1[i][j]['weight'] = euclidean(coord[i],coord[j])
```

Is there a way to remove all the edges to these new nodes except the one edge with the lowest capacity? So since I added 3 nodes i am looking for these 3 nodes to only be connected by the shortest edge to the rest of the graph.

I was thinking about using this

```
for i in range (38,41):
    for j in range (0,38)):
```

and using an if statement to remove edges if they are longer than the current shortest edge but i dont know how

Comment: For each pair of nodes you first need to find the shortest edge. Then you can remove the other edges.

Comment: Is this even possible to do within one loop? I was thinking something like this: `for i in range (38,41):
    for j in range (0,len(38)):
        print(Z1[i][j]['weight'])
        while Z1.degree(i)!= 1:
            getal = 100000
            if Z1[i][j]['weight'] < getal:
                getal = Z1[i][j]['weight'] 
                if getal = Z1[i][j]['weight']:
                    remove all edges
                    add edge i,j                  `#i know this isnt all code and just an idea but i dont think this idea wil give the shortest edge for all nodes

Comment: You need to loop over the edges twice, first to find the shortest, then to remove the others. And use `==`, not `=`, in your comparison.

Comment: What should happen if there are two or more edges with the same lowest capacity?

Comment: I guess pick one random, but think the odds of 2 edges having the same weightare extremely small.

Comment: Is it possible for the output of one loop to be part of the input for the second loop? because it needs to be something the model can do itself in a single run. I think it what also makes it hard is that the output of the first loop should be multiple edges(the shortest path for every node) not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this approach would work, but one option is to find the shortest path from the initial 37 nodes and then select the shortest one. Something like (pseudocode only):

```py
# compute all shortest paths
short_paths = [nx.shortest_path(i, j) for i in range(38) for j in range(38,41)]

# sort by length
short_paths = sorted(short_paths, key=lambda x: len(x))

# this will keep the shortest path to one of the 3 new nodes
# to compute the shortest (weighted) path to all 3 nodes
# an extra restriction on paths will be needed (to ensure that
# the path includes all of the 3 nodes
path_to_keep = short_paths[0]
```

One final thing is that instead of removing paths, you could create a copy of the `Z1` graph (or whatever is the prior network) and then add the final path to it using `nx.add_path(G, final_path)` [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.add_path.html).